# php linking 2 pages and background image

Tags: php, image, hyperlink

I need help linking 2 webpages together in php, I want my user to click on a button and then move on to the next page ? is there any code for that

Also how do i add background image to cover my entire php website

Comment: PHP `header("location:...")` or JS `location.href` is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

To create a redirection in PHP, we use header("location:*your_url*"). I let you go to the PHP documentation to see how to use it : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Then to integrate an image that "covers" your entire page, it is CSS. You use background-image on your body tag (how to use it : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Good luck! :)